# Need help in improving the efficiency to run the code faster

Tags: python, asynchronous, python-asyncio

Need help in improving the efficiency to run the code faster. I am using the following code and using the asyncio module but my code is still not running in asychronous manner and I am not sure what i am doing wrong. I went through several stackoverflow threads but didn't really help. Any help will be really appreciated:

''''

```
import os
import asyncio


async def get_size(start_path='.'):
    total_size = 0
    for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(start_path):
        for f in filenames:
            fp = os.path.join(dirpath, f)
            # skip if it is symbolic link
            if not os.path.islink(fp):
                total_size += os.path.getsize(fp)
    print(total_size)


def check_folder(folder_path1):
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    tasks = [get_size(folder_path2) for folder_path2 in folder_path1]
    loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.gather(*tasks))


folder_path_deduced = [r'\\WP200\DesknetCW\Apps\App\\_config',
                       r'\\WP101\DesknetCW\Apps\App\\_config',
                       r'\\WD102\DesknetCW\Apps\App\\_config',
                       r'\\WD100\DesknetCW\Apps\App\\_config']
check_folder(folder_path_deduced)
```

''''

Comment: In order to benefit from asyncio your code needs to await something. Typically this could come in the form of I/O. You’ll have more success with concurrent.futures than asyncio.

Comment: Thanks I am still very new to coding. Will definitely look into using concurrent.futures instead. Thanks for looking into it